# Add an image dynamically to this beautiful frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a beautifully animated border in pure CSS.

What if we want this animated borders as a frame and add an image as the content inside it.

When I add the image it just overlays the frame, But I want to put the image inside the frame, not over it.

I have tried my best but I can't find a solution without a hand.

Here is what I've tried (I need to add the image dynamically using javascript):

```js
//addimage(); // uncomment this to add the image to the frame
function addimage(){
  
let pictureSource = 'https://www.architectureartdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ArchitectureArtdesigns-8.jpg';

let image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute("id", "shot");
var node = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
node[0].appendChild(image);
image.src = `${pictureSource}`;
let shot = document.getElementById("shot");

}
```

```css
html,
body,
.box .content {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;
}

.box {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 150%;
 height: 150%;
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
   white 0%,
   white 7.5px,
   hotpink 7.5px,
   hotpink 15px,
   white 15px,
   white 22.5px,
   hotpink 22.5px,
   hotpink 30px);
 transform: translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%) rotate(-45deg);
 animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

.box .content {
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 flex-direction: column;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 z-index: 2;
}

.box,
.box .content {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px deeppink,
    0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),
    inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.box .content h2 {
 color: deeppink;
}

.box .content p {
 color: dimgray;
}

@keyframes animate {
 from {
  background-position: 0;
 }

 to {
  background-position: 0 450px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it as background of content:

```js
addimage(); // uncomment this to add the image to the frame
function addimage(){
  
let pictureSource = 'https://www.architectureartdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ArchitectureArtdesigns-8.jpg';

var node = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
node[0].style.background='url("'+pictureSource+'") center/cover'

}
```

```css
html,
body,
.box .content {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;
}

.box {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 150%;
 height: 150%;
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
   white 0%,
   white 7.5px,
   hotpink 7.5px,
   hotpink 15px,
   white 15px,
   white 22.5px,
   hotpink 22.5px,
   hotpink 30px);
 transform: translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%) rotate(-45deg);
 animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

.box .content {
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 flex-direction: column;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 z-index: 2;
}

.box,
.box .content {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px deeppink,
    0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),
    inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.box .content h2 {
 color: deeppink;
}

.box .content p {
 color: dimgray;
}

@keyframes animate {
 from {
  background-position: 0;
 }

 to {
  background-position: 0 450px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want you can simplify the code of the animation like below:

```js
addimage(); // uncomment this to add the image to the frame
function addimage() {

  let pictureSource = 'https://www.architectureartdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ArchitectureArtdesigns-8.jpg';

  var node = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
  node[0].style.background = 'url("' + pictureSource + '") center/cover'

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.box {  
 border-radius: 10px;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0 7.5px, hotpink 0 15px) 
    0 0/21.21px 21.21px;  /* 21.21px = sqrt(2) * 15px */
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

.box .content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;  
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px deeppink, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin:15px;
}


@keyframes animate {
  to {
    background-position: 21.21px 21.21px; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more question: what if we want to set `.box {
 width: 90vw;
 height: 85vh;}`

Comment: @foxer not the box but you have to adjust the width/height of content

Comment: the width/height of  .box .content doesn't change the size correctly

Comment: you need to account for margin. try `calc(90vw - 30px)` for example

Comment: @foxer simply like this: https://jsfiddle.net/957my1ah/ no need another quesiton

Comment: You saved my life Temani Afif, Thanks a lot... Now it's time to learn,,

Answer (score 1):

Another option: set `.content` to `overflow: hidden`

And to help preserve the illusion that the frame is on top of the image, and an `:after` pseudo element to `.box` with an inset shadow.

```js
addimage(); // uncomment this to add the image to the frame
function addimage(){
  
let pictureSource = 'https://www.architectureartdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ArchitectureArtdesigns-8.jpg';

let image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute("id", "shot");
var node = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
node[0].appendChild(image);
image.src = `${pictureSource}`;
let shot = document.getElementById("shot");

}
```

```css
html,
body,
.box .content {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;
}

.box {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 150%;
 height: 150%;
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
   white 0%,
   white 7.5px,
   hotpink 7.5px,
   hotpink 15px,
   white 15px,
   white 22.5px,
   hotpink 22.5px,
   hotpink 30px);
 transform: translateX(-20%) translateY(-20%) rotate(-45deg);
 animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box .content {
  overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 flex-direction: column;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 z-index: 2;
}

.box,
.box .content {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px deeppink,
    0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),
    inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.box .content h2 {
 color: deeppink;
}

.box .content p {
 color: dimgray;
}

@keyframes animate {
 from {
  background-position: 0;
 }

 to {
  background-position: 0 450px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    
  </div>
</div>
```